# Keep view above keyboard - when keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Currently, when I select an `EditText` in my application and the keyboard appears, the layout/view automatically adjusts to show the full `EditText` just above the keyboard, if it would have been below, otherwise.

Is there any way to set a different `View` to be just above the keyboard when it shows up? I have a button just below the `EditText` and I would like to have it just above the keyboard, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

put that button and `EditText` into a layout and make that layout `gravity` top, or in Button's attributes add this line

```
android:layout_below="id of edittext"
```

Hope these help.

Comment: That will push the view up far enough for the `Button` to still show? What if I have two `EditText`s?

Comment: using this attribute makes sure button is just below of your editText, so you can still see that button, so if you have another EditText, in your second EditText put this attribute with id of EditText #1 and in Button put this attribute with id of EditText #2

Comment: Well, that doesn't work at all.. The button is still hidden by the keyboard.